# Unable to import botbuilder in python (Pycharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, botframework

I tried importing the python package via Pycharm.

```
import sys
import traceback
from datetime import datetime
from http import HTTPStatus

from aiohttp import web
from aiohttp.web import Request, Response, json_response
from botbuilder.core import (
    BotFrameworkAdapterSettings,
    TurnContext,
    BotFrameworkAdapter,
)
from botbuilder.core.integration import aiohttp_error_middleware
from botbuilder.schema import Activity, ActivityTypes
```

Message from the compiler.
Unresolved reference

Comment: Can you post the full error message?

Comment: do you have a bot builder installed in your python environment?

Comment: Did you install the dependencies? Importing the package only tells the program what that package is and where to find it. If the package is not present on your system, it cannot be found.